# Bootstrap 3: Thumbnail caption text wrapping to second line makes container height stretch

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The same question exists for Bootstrap 2 but was unanswered. Hopefully for Bootstrap 3 there will be someone up to the task :-).
Please note that there is also another problem. With lower screen resolutions the text is not only breaking the container shape, it also breaks out of the container.
Thanks in advance!
I have the following code:

```
    <div class="col-md-1">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="islauncher:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.exe">
    <img alt="PowerPoint" src="/sites/hedevenv/AppImages/PowerPoint.jpg">
    <div class="caption" style="align-content: center;">PowerPoint</div>
    </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: well, I don't know what the context is and I don't know why are you using a col-md-1, but based in your example, Bootstrap works EXACTLY as supposed. You're right, at some point, which is EXACTLY 80px, the word "PowerPoint" overlaps teh container, but I can't imagine which device could you be using that is 80px width. See http://www.bootply.com/8TNBYzWXvq with more text added and how it works exactly as expected. If this is NOT what you mean, please re-write your question, add context and any additional CSS

Comment: I'm using col-md-1 to place a number of thumbnails with applications icons. They look like apps on the screen and each of them has a caption.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
I resolved this in the following manner:
                                                                                                     1. Between each col-md-1 gave margin (bottom, left, right) of 20px.
2. Placed the caption outside of the container, below it and gave each caption another 10px bottom margin.

Now it all looks ok, however it would be nice to get other ideas for those cases where you don't have 20px around each thumbnail and you cannot put the caption below.